# osmnx nearest_nodes finding a node that is 5000 meters away from my gps coordinates

Tags: python, osmnx

I am trying to use osmnx to find the shortest path between two locations. If I want to use the function shortest_path, I need the nodes that are near from my gps point. When I use the function nearest_nodes, the output is a node that is around 5000 meters away from the gps coordinate. Is there a reason as to why this happens? Here is the code

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox

graph_area = 'Los Angeles, California, United States'
mode = 'all'

#G = ox.graph_from_place(graph_area, network_type=mode,simplify=False)
#G = ox.add_edge_speeds(G)
#G = ox.add_edge_travel_times(G)
#print("a")

#ox.save_graphml(G, "LA2.graphml") #
    
G = ox.load_graphml("LA2.graphml")

start_lat = 33.8254852
start_lon = -118.240463

start_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, start_lon, start_lat,return_dist=True)

print(start_node)

print('lat:' + str(G.nodes[start_node[0]]['y']))
print('lon:' + str(G.nodes[start_node[0]]['x']))
```

Am I doing something wrong? The printed result gives me these coordinates

Latitude: 33.8462657
Longitude: -118.2883998

When looking at the node coordinates I was not expecting to get the same coordinates as the orginal ones, but I was also not expecting something too far.

Here is the coordinates in openstreetmap (red is the node and green is the original coordinates):

[Two coordinate points plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdaSZ.jpg)

I am not sure what could be the cause

I tried changing the network type of my graph as well as changing the simplify parameter in the graph_from_place function.

Since I can see a point in the openstreetmap map, I was expecting to obtain a node that was closer to my original coordinates

Comment: Your coordinates are in the city of Carson. You requested a network within the city of LA. OSMnx is finding the nearest node in your network (which you constrained to the LA city borders) to those coordinates in Carson. Hence they're a few km apart.

Comment: I created another graph that includes Carson and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much!